# How to get the right input to get my ArrayList's index?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I'm trying to get my ArrayList's index via indexOf. So far, I've got

My ArrayList: `public static ArrayList<Shop> allShops = new ArrayList();`

That what is supposed to get the index

```
Scanner editShop = new Scanner(System.in);
String shopToEdit = editShop.nextLine();
int i = allShops.indexOf(shopToEdit);
System.out.println(i); //see what our index is (returns -1 because the var doesn't seem to get the right input)
EditFunc.edit(i);
```

and this, that is supposed to change my arraylist

```
public static void edit(int index){
    //change array with given input in edit
    //TODO: Make it so they can choose what to edit
    //with booleans if editTrueName = false and then later on make it true again

    System.out.println("Enter the new shop name:");
    Scanner editedShopAttribute = new Scanner(System.in);
    String editedShopName = editedShopAttribute.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the new shop location:");
    String editedShopLocation = editedShopAttribute.nextLine();
    Shop EditedVar = new Shop();
    EditedVar.createShop(editedShopName,editedShopLocation);
    allShops.set(index, EditedVar);

}
```

I've copied the values that debugger showed me and replaced them with that, but it still doesn't seem to work. Am I taking in the wrong kind of data? What can I try?

If there's something that looks wrong with my code, I'm always up to try and make it better.

Comment: You are searching for the index of a `String`. Not a `Shop`.

Comment: @azurefrog, so I would need to take the hashcode of said value and check if it's equal?

Comment: No, you would need to create a `Shop` object and search for that. Since that makes little sense, you should consider to change the `List<Shop>` to a `Map<String, Shop>` so you can directly lookup a `Shop` by `name`. That will also perform better, since it's not a sequential search.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it with a `Map<String, Shop>`? That way you could use the `shopName` as a key.

By the way, as I see your new with java and OOP, I strongly recommend you read Clean Code, by Robert C. Martin, its a game-changing book.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can make what you want work with an Array.  The reason as pointed out in one of the comments is that you are looking for a String, but the Array contains Shop(s).  Since a Shop contains more than just the ShopName, you will never be able to find it this way.   You should use a "Map" for such purposes:

```
public static Map<String, Shop> allShopsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

If you add all the shops to this map, then when you get a ShopName as an input, you merely need to do:

```
Shop shopToEdit = allShopsMap.get(inputShopName);
```

then call the set methods on this object to alter name and location.